# String pattern matching with tcl

Tags: tcl, gtkwave

I am new to tcl and am trying to only capture a user-specified hierarchy depth of the following:

```
top.run.end
top.run.something.end

top.simple.end1     
top.simple.end2

top.simple.something.end1
top.simple.something.end2

top.simple.something.else.end    
top.simple.something.else.other.name.end
```

I would like to only capture the final element in a hierarchy that does not continue with more elements deliminated by a ".". I.e. I would like to append all instances to a list (final element name could be anything).

If the user wants to select the 2nd hierarchy level, the comparison should only allow these elements from above:

```
top.run.end
top.simple.end1     
top.simple.end2
```

If the user specifies the 3rd hierarchy level, then I would like to grab these elements:

```
top.simple.something.end1
top.simple.something.end2
```

4th hierarchy level:

```
top.simple.something.else.end
```

So on and so forth... I have all the code written except the string comparison, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to do what I want.

```
set num_hierarchy 3; # how many levels deap to search for "end"
set num_facs      [ gtkwave::getNumFacs ]; # returns number of elements in file

for {set group_to_add 1} {$group_to_add <= $num_hierarchy} {incr group_to_add} {
    set wave [list]

    for {set i 0} {$i < $num_facs } {incr i} {
        set fac_name [ gtkwave::getFacName $i ]; #returns string in form noted above

        set indx [string <how to compare strings??> $fac_name]
        if {$indx == <match>} {
            lappend wave "$fac_name"
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I understand why you are doing the loops like in your question, so I'll show a slightly different code snippet. I believe you should easily be able to implement the solution in your own if I can show you how mine works. The matching is done by counting the number of dots:

```
set elements {
  top.run.end
  top.run.something.end
  top.simple.end1     
  top.simple.end2
  top.simple.something.end1
  top.simple.something.end2
  top.simple.something.else.end    
  top.simple.something.else.other.name.end
}

set depth_required 3
set wave [list]

foreach element $elements {
  # initial length of element
  set i_len [string length $element]

  # final length of element after removing dots
  set f_len [string length [string map {. ""} $element]]

  # thus number of dots
  set n_dots [expr {$i_len-$f_len}]

  # if the number equals the required hierarchy, then we got one
  if {$n_dots == $depth_required} {
    lappend wave $element
  }
}
```

`wave` then contains:

```
top.run.something.end top.simple.something.end1 top.simple.something.end2
```

---

You could use `regsub` (which can directly return the number of substitutions performed) or split the element on dots then count of the number of resulting sub-elements as well, but I found [this wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Counting+characters+in+a+string) where it shows using `string map` is the fastest method overall.

Comment: @glennjackman I know, it is mentioned in the wiki I linked but it's slower than using string map.

Comment: @glennjackman No problem. I'm actually glad you go around checking the answers and sometimes add more to what's already there, it's really helpful ^^

Comment: @Jerry Sorry about that, my description for what I wanted wasn't perfect. However, what you provided is exactly what I need and I can get it over the goal line from here. Thank you!